# Microsoft Access Group by

Tags: ms-access

is there a way to group my names together and add up the amount of money by name? See Table. Name columns... are from multiple tables. I have about 20 in total, but their value can be repeated in any column. As can be seen, for example, with Michaela. I also have a date filter there. If I make a query on only one column, the names are grouped together and the amounts are added up, but I would like to have a set of all columns.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MOLL.png)

One column works fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozl4R.png)

Comment: `Name columns... are from multiple tables` -- Already feels like a database design problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a union query to collect the data:

```sql
Select NameField1 As FullName, SumField1 As Amount From Table1
Union All
Select NameField2, SumField2 From Table1
Union All
Select NameField1, SumField1 From Table2

--- etc.
```

Now, use this query as source in yet a query:

```sql
Select FullName, Sum(Amount) As TotalAmount
From YourUnionQuery
Group By FullName
```